# Creating a namedtuple from a list

Tags: python, namedtuple

Consider a list  variable  **t**

```
In [55]: t
Out[55]:
['1.423',
 '0.046',
 '98.521',
 '0.010',
 '0.000',
 '0.000',
 '5814251520.0',
 '769945600.0',
 '18775908352.0',
 '2.45024350208e+11',
 '8131.903',
 '168485.073',
 '0.0',
 '0.0',
 '0.022',
 '372.162',
 '1123.041',
 '1448.424']
```

Now consider a **namedtuple** 'Point':

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'usr sys idl wai hiq siq  used  buff  cach  free
    read  writ recv  send majpf minpf alloc  vmfree')
```

How do we convert the variable t to a Point?  The most obvious (to me anyways..) approach - of just providing the list as a constructor argument - does not work:

```
In [57]: Point(t)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-635019d8b551> in <module>()
----> 1 Point(t)

TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 19 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Point(*t)` to expand the contents of `t` as arguments to the `Point` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

More efficient solution: Use the [special `_make` alternate constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make) to directly construct the `namedtuple` from an arbitrary iterable without creating additional intermediate `tuple`s (as star-unpacking to the main constructor requires). Runs faster, less memory churn:

```
Point._make(t)
```

Despite the name, `_make` *is* part of the public API; it's named with a leading underscore to avoid conflicts with field names (which aren't allowed to begin with an underscore).